# How to keep a lot of controls in a mfc form?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I just found out there is a limit for the number of controls that a mfc dialog can hold, I have near 653 controls, the dialog holds just 332 of them, I searched for a solution, some suggested property sheets and property pages, but I dont's want to distribute these 653 controls in some tabs! I want all of them in one tab, so, what else can I do except using tab control or property sheets? Is it possible at all?

This is the form
[image]

Comment: I know that the resource editor has some limits, but that shouldn't carry over to the dialog itself. How are you creating these controls?

Comment: which version of Visual C++ are you using?  I did a quick search and someone indicated that VS2010 doesn't have this limitation.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I have a tab control on a form, I added some dialogs as resources to the solution, and the tab control uses these dialogs as tab pages, one of these resources should hold these 653 controls, 652 static text controls and one button, and I used visual studio toolbox to add controls to dialogs, I didn't add them programmatically.

Comment: @Nerdtron : I'm using VS2005, but I have VS2010 too. I'll try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that some kind of grid control is what you are after. It is a single control in a form of a table that contains many cells. Both table and cells can be customized. Code Project has a whole section dedicated to [grid controls](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/#Grid+Control). Here are first few from that section, free of charge:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3176/The-ALXGrid-Control-Library
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8/MFC-Grid-control-2-27
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2879/Virtual-Grid-Control-1-04

Answer (score 1):

653 controls? Seriously? No matter if the resource editor can handle it, such programming style is simply forbidden! Also, it's a waste of window handles. You should consider using a list/tree instead.

Create your controls programmatically! Inherit `CWnd` and create your [own control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521/Creating-Custom-Controls). Then add an array of your controls and dynamically create them in `OnCreate`.

Comment: "Simply forbidden"? I'd love to see documentation to back that up, but I assume it's hyperbole. And why create your own control if `Static` does exactly what you need?

Comment: We all not its not forbidden, but 650 controls on a dialog raises a big red warning flag in my head too.

Comment: @dwo : yes, you are right, but list is not good for what I want to show to the clients, but a grid, table or something like that is perfec, But MFC does not have something like that,does it?!
Actually I'm creating a table with these 653 controls! 30 rows and 20 columns